# Android map api cannot find com.google.settings

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapsandgps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Maps"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**i added also android api key but when program runs i get error**

09-27 21:03:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapsandgps/com.example.mapsandgps.Maps}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.example.mapsandgps.Maps.onCreate(Maps.java:24)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  ... 11 more
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:237)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  ... 20 more
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to specify an API Key for each MapView.  See the MapView documentation for details.
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:273)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:254)
09-27 21:03:48.576: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  ... 24 more
09-27 21:03:48.786: E/dalvikvm(215): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

Answer (score 2):

you are probably trying to run the application in an incorrect version of target API on your virtual machine:

[image: VM definition]

Select a target version that shows "Google APIs" in the beginig of the name-

good luck.

Comment: i think that isn't solve it.... i have same error, Yunus can you tell something if it solved the error? thnks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing things in your manifest:

1) Permissions required by Google Maps (in `<manifest>`):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

2) Meta data, last elements of `<application>` (ie after activities and services):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_api_key_goes_here" />
```

Refer to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_google_play_services_version_to_your_apps_manifest) for further instruction.